# Aggregating JMS messajes from many destinations to a single queue

Tags: jms, weblogic, jms-topic

What can be the best way to aggregate messages from many different sources (actually queues/topics) into a single queue/topic and then consume it. I am trying to design an application to receive messages from different topics in JMS using weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own "aggregator" as a stand-alone Java application:

- For each queue/topic have a reader in its own thread.
- Each reader sends its received message again on a "aggregate queue".
- Have another thread to listen on the "aggregate queue".

As a variation, you could use a JVM Queue (like `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`) as the "aggregate queue". This is faster, does not require another MQ queue, does not need network bandwidth, but it's not persistent.

---

Another idea is to use a "Message driven bean (MDB)" for each incoming queue/topic:

- Again, each of these MDBs just reads the message and resends it to the "aggregate queue".
- Have another MDB listening on the "aggregate queue".

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions on quality requirements. I belive you have to consider them.
They will be highly relate with your technical solution.

1. is that message loss acceptable?
   client ack could be considered. 
   e.g. A memory queue sit in middle, e.g. incoming queue1...n -> ArrayBlockingQueue in memory -> outgoing queue. The data in the ArrayBlockingQueue , will lost when app crash.
2. is that message duplicate acceptable for the single outgoing queue?
   I would suggest yes.
   Set applicable level PossibleDuplicateFlag to make the client aware of that.
3. how fast the incoming messages per second on the diff incoming queue? 
   one queue session has only a uniqe thread. Performance has to be considered in advance.